# Launching a thread from a loop and passing Loop ID

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

I just started playing around with threading today and I ran into something that I dont understand.

```
public void Main()
{ 
    int maxValue = 5;
    for (int ID = 0; ID < maxValue; ID++)
    {
        temp(ID);
    }
}

public void temp(int i)
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

As basic as it gets which works fine, but when I try to create a new thread for each, it only passes the maxValue.  Please disregard how bad this is to do, I only wrote it this way as a simplistic example.

```
public void Main()
{ 
    int maxValue = 5;
    for (int ID = 0; ID < maxValue; ID++)
    {
        threads.Add(new Thread(() => temp(myString, rowID)));
        threads[rowID].Start();
    }
}

public void temp(string myString, int i)
{
    string _myString = myString;

    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

Given this, I have two questions:
1) Why doesnt a the method get called on a new thread passing the ID?
2) How should this correctly be coded?

Comment: well first of all, you have undeclared rowID variable. Rename both occurences to ID and it WILL work ALL RIGHT. Answer below is OBSOLETE!

Comment: rowID is a typo.. if that is changed to ID it doesnt work Jons answer is correct.

Comment: @mnn: No it won't. How familiar are you with how captured variables work in C#?

Comment: Jon Skeet: AFAIK value types are saved just as in anonymous delegates, so no problem with that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you've only got one `ID` variable, and it's being captured. The variable is only being *read* when the code in the new thread is actually executed, which will often be after your main thread has finished its loop, leaving `ID` at `maxValue`. Take a copy on each loop iteration, so that you capture a different variable each time:

```
for (int ID = 0; ID < maxValue; ID++)
{
    int copy = ID;
    threads.Add(new Thread(() => temp(myString, copy)));
    threads[rowID].Start();
}
```

This is a common mistake with closures. Read [my article comparing C# and Java closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) for more information. The same thing happens with `foreach`, by the way - and that's even more confusing, as it *reads* like you've got a new variable each time:

```
foreach (string url in urls)
{
    // Aargh, bug! Don't do this!
    new Thread(() => Fetch(url)).Start();
}
```

Again, you only end up with one variable. You need each delegate to capture a separate variable, so again you use a copy:

```
foreach (string url in urls)
{
    string urlCopy = url;
    new Thread(() => Fetch(urlCopy)).Start();
}
```

Comment: You've made the SAME mistake as DataPimp made. You don't need to have another variable, just rename rowID to ID and it'll work ok.

Comment: Thank you very much, Im not sure I understand 100% on why the first code I posted gets executed but the second doesnt (I guess it kinda makes sense) but Im definitely going to read that article of yours and hopefully that will clarify things.

Comment: @mnn: No it won't. You'll end up with the captured variable problem. It may not *always* show, but you'll definitely have a bug. Using a captured loop variable when starting threads is horribly bug-prone. I assumed the use of `rowID` was just a typo, given that the use of an undeclared variable is a *compile time* bug rather than an *execution time* bug.