# Run multiple threads at the same time without any running twice or failing

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I run some threads at the same time without "running twice" or "failing" one of them?  I will explain my question with an example:

```
private int count = 0;
private HashSet<int> hs_pages = new HashSet<int>();
```

---

```
for (int page = 1; page <= 10; page++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(unused => my_method(page));
    thread.Name = "Thread - " + page.ToString();
    thread.Start();
}
while(count < 10)
{

}
```

and `my_method()` is implemented as:

```
public void my_method(int page)
{
    if (hs_pages.Add(page))
    {    
           count++;
          //My Codes
    }
    else
    {
          MessageBox.Show("this is duplicate of page : " + page.ToString());
    }
}
```

after running this code I figured out some pages (1-10) don't run and some pages run twice.
so the `while()` never ends because of those duplicates and fails.

How can I fix those duplicates and failures?

My meaning of fail is not "Error", I mean for example `my_method(4)` never runs and my meaning of duplicate is for example `my_method(3)` runs twice.

I know there are other ways such as `Parallel.ForEach`, but I want to learn how to use the Thread Class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching a thread from a loop and passing Loop ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423680/launching-a-thread-from-a-loop-and-passing-loop-id)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're closing over the loop variable.

Closures close over *variables* not over *values*.  The lambda that you are creating isn't taking a copy of the current value of `page` within the body of the loop, it's creating a reference to that variable and it will access that variable's value when the anonymous method is actually *executed* at some point in the future.  By the time that execution actually happens the loop has already continued on and incremented the value some number of times (we won't know how many; it'll depend on how the threads are scheduled).

Make a copy of `page` that's local to the body of the loop so that each closure is over a different variable, rather than a single variable that is being mutated:

```
for (int page = 1; page <= 10; page++)
{
    int pageCopy = page;
    Thread thread = new Thread(unused => my_method(pageCopy , count));
    thread.Name = "Thread - " + pageCopy.ToString();
    thread.Start();
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be doing a busy wait to wait for all of the threads to finish; that's extraordinarily wasteful of system resources to spend lots of CPU time spinning around in the while loop doing nothing.  Instead put all of the `Thread` object that you create into a `List<Thread>` when you create them and then loop through the list again when you're done and call `Join` on them all to wait for them to finish.

Comment: @MoonLight - Did you read the answer in the link I provided in my "possible duplicate" comment?

Comment: I'm going to delete my comments about `count`, since that's no longer an issue, and they seem to be causing confusion.

Comment: so sorry, thanks a lot for attention by the way. both John Saunders & Servy.

Comment: This answer ended hours of frustration wondering why I was getting inconsistent results from my program. Thank you.